# Android Tablet freezing because of download

Tags: android

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note. I was downloading a pdf file and after that my tablet is acting weirdly. Whenever I turn it off and back on, the screen would be unresponsive except for the back button and power button. Restarting doesn't work. Sometimes, when there is a prompt like choosing a browser, it sends me straight to the browser. When I go back to the home screen, everything works until I turn it off and back on again. I wonder whether I don't have to factory reset my device to solve the problem. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting cache memory (reboot+shutdown button + upper button (normally)).
That may help

Comment: I reset the cache memory, but it's still not working.